# How to fix Next.js 14.1 prerendering Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I recently upgraded my Next.js 14.01 to 14.1 and I got this error while doing the build in my app how can I fix this error?

it says :

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/collections". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
 ⨯ useSearchParams() should be wrapped in a suspense boundary at page "/contactus". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/missing-suspense-with-csr-bailout
Error occurred prerendering page "/contactus". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
 ⨯ useSearchParams() should be wrapped in a suspense boundary at page "/login". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/missing-suspense-with-csr-bailout
Error occurred prerendering page "/login". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
 ⨯ useSearchParams() should be wrapped in a suspense boundary at page "/orders". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/missing-suspense-with-csr-bailout
Error occurred prerendering page "/orders". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
 ⨯ useSearchParams() should be wrapped in a suspense boundary at page "/register". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/missing-suspense-with-csr-bailout
Error occurred prerendering page "/register". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

 ✓ Generating static pages (21/21) 
> Export encountered errors on following paths:
    /_not-found
    /admin/add-products/page: /admin/add-products
    /admin/manage-orders/page: /admin/manage-orders
    /admin/manage-products/page: /admin/manage-products
    /admin/page: /admin
    /cart/page: /cart
    /checkout/page: /checkout
    /collections/page: /collections
    /contactus/page: /contactus
    /login/page: /login
    /orders/page: /orders
    /register/page: /register
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

[image]

Please help me to fix this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The follwing pages renders a Client Component that uses `usePathnames`.

[image]

(Maybe this client component is in layout.tsx)

This hook gets the searchparams from the `Request` which is not available at the building time. Using this hook will disable Static PreRendering for the entire route. The error suggest you to benefit from Streaming and partially pre-render the parts of the route that doesn't depend on request time values.

To fix:

1. Find the component that uses `useSearchParams` (You can use the IDE search)
2. wrap it in a `<Suspense>` boundary:

```js
import {useSearchParams} from "next/navigation";

function MyComponent() {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams()
  // ...
}
```

```js
// app/page.tsx
import {Suspense} from "react";

export default function Page() {
  return <div>
    <h1>...</h1>
    <Suspense fallback={<>Loading...</>}>
      <MyComponent />
    </Suspense>
  </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add loading.tsx to the root of app. and if you made any group routing then just add loading.tsx there too. that's worked for me