Static export with errors Next.JS 14 with App Router
I try to make static export and pre-render all pages with nextjs static export feature, I have pages which need dynamic props but I got errors while compiling:
Error occurred prerendering page "/branche/agriculture-foresterie-ressources-animales-et-halieutiques/13/instituts". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
Architecture of App folder
App
--- branche
--- [slug]
------ [id]
---------page.tsx
---------metiers/page.tsx
---------instituts/page.tsx
......

Institut/page.tsx
import InstitutsContainer from "@/containers/root/branche/instituts";
import { API_URL } from "@/services/api_url.services";
import { BRANCHE_DATA, BranchePageParams } from "@/types";

export const dynamic = "force-static";

async function getAllBranchesParams() {
  const res = await fetch(API_URL.BRANCHE_LIST, { cache: "no-store" });

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch branches");
  }
  const branches: Array<BRANCHE_DATA> = await res
    .json()
    .then((data) => data.branches);
  // console.log(datas);

  return branches.map((branch: BRANCHE_DATA) => ({
    slug: branch.slug,
    id: branch.id.toString(),
  }));
}

export async function generateStaticParams() {
  return getAllBranchesParams().then((res) => {
    return res;
  });
}

async function getData(brancheId: number): Promise<{ branche: BRANCHE_DATA }> {
  const res = await fetch(`${API_URL.BRANCHE_DETAIL}/${brancheId}`, {
    cache: "no-store",
  });
  if (!res.ok) {

    throw new Error("Failed to fetch Instituts");
  }

  return res.json();
}

export default async function InstitutsPage({
  params,
}: {
  params: BranchePageParams;
}) {
  const data = await getData(parseInt(params.id));
  return <InstitutsContainer branche={data?.branche} />;
}

next.config.js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  // reactStrictMode: false,
  // swcMinify: true,
  output: "export",
  trailingSlash: true,
  images: {
    unoptimized: true,
  },
};

module.exports =  nextConfig;

I want to pre-render pages with static export and deploy to an apache server

Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/77914603/18079514

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
